# Highlight some days in codeigniter calendar

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I am using codeigniter calendar library for generating a calendar.
For that I used this code :

```
$this->load->library('calendar');
$myarray= array('2014-09-05','2014-09-12','2014-09-15','2014-09-22');

$data['docs']   =   $this->calendar->generate();
$this->load->view('mycal',$data);
```

I need to display the values in `$myarray` with a red background color.

Comment: Why not do it in the view with simple CSS class?

Comment: `$data['important_days'] = $myarray;` Then modify `views/mycal.php` to add a class to dates appearing in `$important_days`

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to define the **days** that you want to highlight
2. Define the month you want the calendar to generate
3. Pass the array of special dates to the generate() function along with the Year and Month

So you need to bring the followings:

In the controller

```
$this->load->library('calendar');
$myarray= array(
    5=>'2014-09-05', # or you can set as: 5=>'SomeLink'
    12=>'2014-09-12',
    15=>'2014-09-15',
    22=>'2014-09-22'
);

$data['docs'] = $this->calendar->generate(2014,9, $myarray);
$this->load->view('mycal',$data);
```

In the view

```
<style>
#calendar a{
    background: red;
    padding:2px;
}
</style>
<div id="calendar">
    <?php echo $docs; ?>
</div>
```